# Custom buttons imported from an external xib/nib file not responding to button click

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm working on an app that involves a whole bunch of buttons that will be formatted exactly the same way -- same size, layout, color, text labels, etc.  Similar to how it works with "prototype" cells in Table Views and Container Views, I'm trying to create one instance of the "prototype" button as a custom class of UIButton in an external xib that I can pull into the main view controller and repeat as necessary.

I'm not having any trouble bringing in the buttons, and I haven't had any problems customizing the text labels, etc.  So this doesn't feel like an issue where the "prototype" isn't outletted correctly.

What doesn't seem to be working are the actual button taps.

I have two buttons -- button1 and button2, which have been assigned tag=1 and tag=2.  In order to test the button action, I've set up a print statement that prints the tag number of the sender to the console.

If I create a simple, plain button in the main storyboard, and give it a tag number, the button behaves correctly.  But the custom-class buttons don't send anything to the console.

Am I missing a step?  My gut is that there's an extra detail in the external xib that I'm missing...but I would think that the specifics (tag numbers, etc.) need to be associated with each instance, not with the prototype.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button1: customButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: customButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button1.customTitle.text = "This is Button 1"
    button2.customTitle.text = "This is Button 2"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print(sender.tag)

    }
}
```

EDIT: here is the code from the xib where the button is generated.

```
import UIKit

class customButton: UIButton {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

    override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customButton", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you link the button action to `notePressed`?

Comment: In the .swift file associated with the custom .xib, I have an outlet from the button to this code:          

@IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) { ...

Comment: Can you add the code that makes the connection into your question?

Comment: done.  hope that sheds some light on things.

Comment: So, you have an empty `buttonPressed` function in the `customButton` class.  If that's your button action, it makes sense that the view controller function isn't being called.  (Try printing something from the `customButton` action to see what happens.)

Comment: if add print(sender.tag) to the customButton class, then the button "works", but it returns tag=0 to the console no matter which button I press.  I guess that was my initial thought -- that the buttonPressed() function needed to be called from the instance in order to pick up the instance's assigned tag.  Maybe I need to assign a tag in code to each of the instances when I create them in the main VC file?

Comment: I have made an edit to tweak the function name.  It's buttonPressed() not notePressed().  Issue is the same & is not a result of the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now see in your edited answer, you have a contentView added as a subview. Set it's interaction enabled status to false so it wont care about the touches itself, and button action should be fired.

In your button file, maybe in commonInit:

```
contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just to make sure I'm clear -- this goes in the main View Controller file, correct?  Not the .swift file associated with custom xib class, correct?

Comment: @MMac yes it should go in the main ViewController, let me know if it works

Comment: no luck, I'm afraid.  I suspect the issue is on the xib side?

Comment: @MMac I have updated my answer, can you see the bottom of my answer now.

Comment: Yes, it works now, but interestingly, the 2 buttons to which I applied addTarget() (buttons 1 & 2) are now "double-striking", e.g. button 1 prints "1" to the console twice, button 2 prints "2" twice.  I have several other buttons I set up that *don't* call addTarget() that are behaving normally -- so, e.g. button 3, which doesn't have an addTarget statement but IS subject to the isUserInteractionEnabled statement -- is working correctly -- one click = one "3" to the console.  So I guess the answer is simply that contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false is what's needed?

Comment: Yeah sounds like that @MMac just ignore my target addition since you already have IBAction outlet works fine when you set user interaction of contentView to false.

Comment: awesome, thank you for your help!  In the interest of others who find this thread, can you update your answer to leave out the target addition stuff?  I also didn't need the ObjC part -- it works without it.  
I'll accept that as best answer.